# Looking for a paperof Matveev M V, Uspenskii V V 1992

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

The paper which is been looking for is this:

> Matveev M V, Uspenskii V V. On star-compact spaces with a Gδ-diagonal, Zbornik Radova Filosofskogo Fakulteta v Nisu[J]. Ser. Mat, 1992, 6(2): 281-290.

I've tried, however, it is difficult for me to get it. Could somebody help me?

Thanks for any help and links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present this journal is called Filomat. I think you can ask some of Filomat's Edtorial board to send to you this article.

Comment: @Paul: The editors are listed [here](http://www.pmf.ni.ac.rs/pmf/publikacije/filomat/editorial_board.php).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks very muvh.

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome. Good luck with getting a copy.